# End of File (EOF)

Tags: c++, c++11

Hello I've written an algorithm where it prints last number  , but I wonder how to make it  not to print default value of "number" for example(4.94066e-324) when there's no number written in console/file.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
double number;
for (; cin >> number;);
cout << number; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to check wether the first input operation succeeds or not:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double number;

    if(std::cin >> number)
    {
        while (std::cin >> number);

        std::cout << number; 
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "There is no number :(";
    }
}
```

Few things I changed here:

- removed `using namespace std;`, it's [considered bad parctice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- a `while` is better suited for this task than a half-empty `for`

And of course this can be generalized to any `std::basic_istream`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag to check if you have ever got any input, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double number;
    bool flag = false;
    for (; cin >> number;)
        flag = true;
    if(flag)
        cout << number; 
}
```